# How to Install PyOpenCV on Ubuntu

Tags: python

I'm trying to install PyOpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04 using setuptools.  When I tried

```
python setup.py config
```

I got the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name Library
```

I found in an answer to a previous question that the fix was to change

```
from setuptools import Library
```

to

```
from setuptools.extension import Library
```

in setup.py.  Now when I run setup.py, the error occurs in the config.py script it generates:

```
$ python setup.py config
Configuring PyOpenCV via CMake...
<snip>
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:  /home/saul/Downloads/pyopencv/build
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 137, in <module>
import config as C
File "/home/saul/Downloads/pyopencv/config.py", line 1, in <module>
from setuptools import Extension, Library
ImportError: cannot import name Library
```

The first line of config.py contains the same import error.  I can correct config.py of course, but I don't know how to resume the build process.

The text of setup.py from the point of failure is:

```
    import config as C

setup(
name = "pyopencv",
version = C.PYOPENCV_VERSION,
description = DOCLINES[0],
author = 'Minh-Tri Pham',
author_email = 'pmtri80@gmail.com',
url = 'http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/',
license = 'New BSD License',
platforms = 'OS Independent, Windows, Linux, MacOS',
classifiers = filter(None, CLASSIFIERS.split('\n')),
long_description = "\n".join(DOCLINES[2:]),
ext_modules=C.extension_list,
install_requires = ['numpy>=1.2.0'],
package_data = {'pyopencv': ['*.dll']},
include_package_data = True,
# zip_safe = (os.name!='nt'), # thanks to ffmpeg dependency
package_dir={'':'package'},
packages = find_packages('package'),
)
```

Can you tell me how to fix this, or suggest an alternative way to install pyOpenCV?

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/447409/how-to-install-opencv-2-9-for-python? Might be too old, though. If you don't get an answer here, try there.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks.  Has OpenCV-Python replaced pyOpenCV, do you know?  All the pyOpenCV stuff I found was several years old.  I'm just starting with this, and didn't even know enough to look for OpenCV-Python as an alternative.

Comment: to installing python packages, you can also use the pip utilily:

Comment: pip search opencv returns: pyopencv                  - PyOpenCV - A Python wrapper for OpenCV 2.x using Boost.Python and NumPy
using pip install pyopencv. To install pip : sudo apt-get install python-pip

Comment: Thanks Cristiano, but that fails with the error message:  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopencv (from versions: 2.0.wr1.0.1-demo, 2.0.wr1.0.1, 2.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.1, 2.1.0.wr1.0.2, 2.1.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.2.0).  I'm just going to try OpenCV-Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is much simple way to do it, open terminal and type :

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Comment: Check version with `import cv2; cv2.__version__`.  I got `'2.4.8'`.